# Comparing input with certain line of text file

Tags: python

I have tried to code part of a program which compares the input with the fifth line of the text file called name. The file has text on each line, and with the current code it only works if there is only one line of text in the file (blank lines before line 5) but I need it to work when the file has 30 lines of text. 
The text file looks like this:

```
John
James
Bob
Jim
Jack
Harry
Oliver
```

What needs changing to my code:

```
 names = input("enter name: ")
   with open("name") as f:
       for line in f:
           if line[4].split('\n') == names:
               print ("correct")
       else:
           print("incorrect")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("enter name: ")
with open("name") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    if lines[4] == name:
        print("correct")
    else:
        print("incorrect")
```

Your code should be this; the problem with your current code is that you're thinking `line` refers to all the lines, whereas it only refers to the current, successive line- and what you're doing with the `[4]` is selecting the 5th character on that line opposed to the 5th line.

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['John',
   ...: 'James',
   ...: 'Bob',
   ...: 'Jim',
   ...: 'Jack',
   ...: 'Harry',
   ...: 'Oliver']

with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for idx, line in enumerate(f):
        if idx == 4:
            break

print('Correct' if line.rstrip() == input('Name: ') else 'Incorrect')
```

Surprising, there is no significant performance difference between treating the open file as a standard iterable and reading lines into `lines` via `readline()`, even for files with 100,000 names.